# How to delete a key/value inside value field with Dexie.js?

Tags: javascript, browser, indexeddb, dexie

I have a row with value like this below:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "token": "abcd"
}
```

How do I delete and save the value without "token" so it becomes this?

```
{
   "id": 1
}
```

Do I need to first get the object, modify it then save back?

Comment: Yes. Get the object, modify it, and then save it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
function patch(db, id, delta) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const tx = db.transaction('mystore', 'readwrite');
    tx.onerror = (event) => reject(event.target.error);
    tx.oncomplete = () => resolve();
    const store = tx.objectStore('mystore');
    const request = store.get(id);
    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      const object = event.target.result;

      if (!object) {
        reject(new Error(`No matching object for ${id}`));
        return;
      }

      for (const prop in delta) {
         if (typeof delta[prop] === 'undefined') {
           delete object[prop];
         } else {
           object[prop] = delta[prop];
         }
      }

      store.put(object);
    };
  });
}

async function dostuff() {
  let db;
  const id = 1;
  const delta = {
    token: undefined
  };

  try {
    db = await connect();
    await patch(db, id, delta);
  } finally {
    if (db) {
      db.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Dexie, you can use [`Collection.modify()`](https://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.modify()) with a function argument. This will be called with every object in the collection and you can update it them at your convenience, which includes deleting properties.

```js
// update a single object
db.friends.where({ id: 1 }).modify((friend) => { delete friend.token })

// update all objects
db.friends.toCollection().modify((friend) => { delete friend.token })
```